# Julia: Sum of elements in array except element corresponding to chosen index

Tags: arrays, sum, julia

I am summing elements of array and storing it into the dictionary. Key corresponds to the sum of elements in array excluding element with **index == key**. I am trying to do it as one-liner. This is just the simplified example of my code for understanding what I want to do.

Code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = [k => sum(b) for k=a]
```

I tried using **deleteat!**

```
sum(deleteat!(b, k))
```

Sometimes it gives **Bounds error** so I want to come up with better idea but so far no result.

Thanks.

Comment: How about adding all the elements and then subtracting off the one you don't want? (Note that the sum of all the elements is the same whichever element you use, so if you're doing this multiple times you can save computation by doing the sum only once.)

Comment: Your solution is good but not applicable for my real problem. Code above is just for understanding what I want to achieve. I just do not want to post the real code here.

Comment: It is universally true that (sum of all elements except one at index k) = (sum of all elements) - (element at index k), aside from numerical issues (e.g., if the element at index k is enormous and you're working in limited-precision floating-point).

Comment: Incidentally, you *really* don't want to try to do it with `deleteat!` because that *modifies the array you apply it to*.

Comment: In my real code array **b** is constructed with different elements for each iteration over array **a**. I will try subtracting it as you suggested and see what the result will be.

Comment: I tried it. It is not working.

Comment: **Edit:** It is working thanks :) There was just problem with evaluation. Adding brackets solved the problem.

Comment: `[sum([i==j ? zero(eltype(a)) : a[j] for j=1:length(a)]) for i=1:length(a)]`. The element at position `i` is the sum of `a` without `a[i]`. This could be adapted with a different `sum` function to `a` with non-numeric items (with numeric items the subtraction trick works).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan no it is not universally true. Suppose you have the numbers [1,2,3,4] and you want to perform sum(1/(x-2)) then you wouldn't be able to add 1/(2-2) and then subtract it after because of course the number 1/(2-2) is not defined in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The solution above, i.e.:

```
f(a) = [sum([i==j ? zero(eltype(a)) : a[j] for j=1:length(a)]) for i=1:length(a)]
```

I think that will be O(n^2), because it constructs a vector of length a, in order to sum without the element at j, and does that length(a) times to construct the result vector.

Here is my first solution (which should be O(n), n = length(a))

```
g(a) = let s = sum(a) ; [ s-v for v in a ] end
```

and here is another solution (also O(n)), using array operators.

```
h(v) = fill(sum(v), length(v)) - v
```

Here are my benchmark results, after creating a vector z with: `z = rand(1:100000,1000)` As you can see, the fastest is my first solution, with the explicit array comprehension (it's about 1000x faster than the solution given previously in the comments, because it is O(n) instead of O(n^2), and n == 1000.

```
julia> @benchmark f(z)

================ Benchmark Results ========================
     Time per evaluation: 2.59 ms [1.86 ms, 3.32 ms]
Proportion of time in GC: 19.08% [3.56%, 34.59%]
        Memory allocated: 7.79 mb
   Number of allocations: 3003 allocations
       Number of samples: 100
   Number of evaluations: 100
 Time spent benchmarking: 0.34 s


julia> @benchmark g(z)
================ Benchmark Results ========================
     Time per evaluation: 1.77 μs [1.74 μs, 1.79 μs]
Proportion of time in GC: 8.65% [7.34%, 9.95%]
        Memory allocated: 7.97 kb
   Number of allocations: 3 allocations
       Number of samples: 8201
   Number of evaluations: 4959001
         R² of OLS model: 0.952
 Time spent benchmarking: 8.88 s


julia> @benchmark h(z)
================ Benchmark Results ========================
     Time per evaluation: 2.98 μs [2.94 μs, 3.03 μs]
Proportion of time in GC: 10.54% [9.05%, 12.02%]
        Memory allocated: 15.92 kb
   Number of allocations: 5 allocations
       Number of samples: 7601
   Number of evaluations: 2799801
         R² of OLS model: 0.951
 Time spent benchmarking: 8.41 s
```